# How to show events with 2 or less minutes between them from the same user?

Tags: sql, vertica

Imagine I have a table with events in it:

```
id user date                 amount
1  1    29.10.2019 16:35:01  10
2  1    29.10.2019 16:35:29  15
3  2    29.10.2019 16:48:29  12
4  2    29.10.2019 16:55:44  14
```

I would like to see all events like 1 and 2 (there's less than 2 minutes between them; they're from the same user) ordered by user and date.

What I've already tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT id, user, amount, 
datediff(MINUTE, lag(date) OVER (ORDER BY user, d_date), date) 
AS since_past_one
FROM events
) e
where since_past_one <> 0
and since_past_one <= 2
order by user, date
```

Problem is that lag takes value even if it is already a different user's event.

What I would like to see as a result is this:

```
id user date                 amount
1  1    29.10.2019 16:35:01  10
2  1    29.10.2019 16:35:29  15
```

Comment: What do you want to do if you have 3,4,5,6,7,8 events of the same user, all less than 2 secs apart? And do you only need the first row of such a group? You can do much more with Vertica SQL ...

Comment: @marcothesane, thanks for asking. That's the problem I'm working on right now. Yes, I want all events from the same user. And my query won't do that. 
My end goal is to calculate the share of this type of events among all of them and how many users are affected. I'm new at Vertica after year of using Oracle.

UPD: Yes, I definitely want the first row of every group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then let's have a few more rows and such patterns - I put an empty line every time we have a gap of over 2 seconds :

```
WITH input(id,usr,ts,amount) AS ( 
          SELECT 1,1,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:00.0',10.00 
UNION ALL SELECT 1,1,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:01.5',10.26 
UNION ALL SELECT 1,1,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:03.0',10.52 
UNION ALL SELECT 1,1,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:04.5',10.78 
UNION ALL SELECT 1,1,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:06.0',11.03 
UNION ALL SELECT 1,1,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:07.5',11.29 

UNION ALL SELECT 1,1,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:09.0',11.55 
UNION ALL SELECT 1,1,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:10.5',11.81 
UNION ALL SELECT 1,1,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:18.0',13.10 
UNION ALL SELECT 1,1,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:19.5',13.36 
UNION ALL SELECT 1,1,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:21.0',13.62 

UNION ALL SELECT 1,1,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:27.0',14.66 
UNION ALL SELECT 1,1,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:28.5',14.91 

UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:00.0',12.00 
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:01.5',12.10 
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:03.0',12.21 
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:04.5',12.31 

UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:12.0',12.83 
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:13.5',12.93 
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:15.0',13.03 
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:16.5',13.14 

UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:24.0',13.66 
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:25.5',13.76 
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:27.0',13.86 
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,TIMESTAMP '2019-10-29 16:35:28.5',13.97 
) 
SELECT * FROM input;
```

Gives me:

```
 id | usr |          ts           | amount                                  
----+-----+-----------------------+--------
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:00   |  10.00
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:01.5 |  10.26
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:03   |  10.52
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:04.5 |  10.78
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:06   |  11.03
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:07.5 |  11.29
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:09   |  11.55
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:10.5 |  11.81
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:18   |  13.10
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:19.5 |  13.36
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:21   |  13.62
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:27   |  14.66
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:28.5 |  14.91
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:00   |  12.00
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:01.5 |  12.10
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:03   |  12.21
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:04.5 |  12.31
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:12   |  12.83
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:13.5 |  12.93
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:15   |  13.03
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:16.5 |  13.14
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:24   |  13.66
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:25.5 |  13.76
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:27   |  13.86
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:28.5 |  13.97
```

So we want the begin row of each group of rows that are not further apart in time than 2 seconds, for the same user. Vertica can identify such groups. The process is generally called "sessionization". We have the Vertica OLAP function CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT() that does that for us: it starts with 0 for each PARTITION and increments by 1 every time the Boolean expression in the parentheses is true.

```
SELECT                                                                      
  CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(ts - LAG(ts) > INTERVAL '2000 msec') OVER(
    PARTITION BY usr ORDER BY ts
  ) AS session_id
, *
FROM input
```

gives us:

```
 session_id | id | usr |          ts           | amount 
------------+----+-----+-----------------------+--------
          0 |  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:00   |  10.00
          0 |  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:01.5 |  10.26
          0 |  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:03   |  10.52
          0 |  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:04.5 |  10.78
          0 |  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:06   |  11.03
          0 |  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:07.5 |  11.29
          0 |  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:09   |  11.55
          0 |  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:10.5 |  11.81
          1 |  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:18   |  13.10
          1 |  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:19.5 |  13.36
          1 |  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:21   |  13.62
          2 |  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:27   |  14.66
          2 |  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:28.5 |  14.91
          0 |  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:00   |  12.00
          0 |  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:01.5 |  12.10
          0 |  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:03   |  12.21
          0 |  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:04.5 |  12.31
          1 |  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:12   |  12.83
          1 |  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:13.5 |  12.93
          1 |  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:15   |  13.03
          1 |  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:16.5 |  13.14
          2 |  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:24   |  13.66
          2 |  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:25.5 |  13.76
          2 |  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:27   |  13.86
          2 |  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:28.5 |  13.97
```

And, to get the first row of each group, we use the Vertica specific *analytic LIMIT clause* :

```
WITH
with_sess_id AS (
  SELECT
    CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(ts - LAG(ts) > INTERVAL '2000 msec') OVER(
      PARTITION BY usr ORDER BY ts
    ) AS session_id
  , *
  FROM input
)
SELECT 
  id
, usr
, ts
, amount
FROM with_sess_id
LIMIT 1 OVER(PARTITION BY usr,session_id ORDER BY ts);
```

You get:

```
 id | usr |         ts          | amount 
----+-----+---------------------+--------
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:00 |  10.00
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:18 |  13.10
  1 |   1 | 2019-10-29 16:35:27 |  14.66
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:00 |  12.00
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:12 |  12.83
  3 |   2 | 2019-10-29 16:35:24 |  13.66
```

If I understood well your last question, you would like to have the average number of rows per session as we have determined above, and the average of the average amount per session as we have determined above. That would then be, if I understood your question right:

```
WITH
with_sess_id AS (
  SELECT
    CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(ts - LAG(ts) > INTERVAL '2000 msec') OVER(
      PARTITION BY usr ORDER BY ts
    ) AS session_id
  , *
  FROM input
)
,
session_summary AS (
  SELECT
    usr
  , session_id
  , COUNT(*) AS rows_per_session
  , AVG(amount) AS avg_amt_per_session
  FROM with_sess_id
  GROUP BY 1,2
  -- this returns:
  --  usr | session_id | rows_per_session | avg_amt_per_session 
  -- -----+------------+------------------+---------------------
  --    1 |          0 |                8 |              10.905
  --    1 |          1 |                3 |               13.36
  --    1 |          2 |                2 |              14.785
  --    2 |          0 |                4 |              12.155
  --    2 |          1 |                4 |             12.9825
  --    2 |          2 |                4 |             13.8125
)
SELECT
  AVG(rows_per_session) AS avg_rows_per_session
, AVG(avg_amt_per_session) AS avg_avg_amount_per_session
FROM session_summary;
avg_rows_per_session | avg_avg_amount_per_session
 ----------------------+----------------------------
      4.16666666666667 |                         13
```

Comment: That makes everything much easier. Using session id and group by I could caluculate average amount per session with this type of user behaviour. Thank you!

Comment: but how can I give an unique number to each session and filter single event from a user in order to calculate average number of event within this type of session of events (>1 with less than x minutes between them), and averge sum of all amounts within session?

Comment: Do I get that right: You want to have the average number of rows per session, and the average of (the average amount per session)?

Comment: Thank you for your update! It helped me a lot. I wanted to calculate the average sum of groupped events. But it is easy thing to do in your query. I should replace AVG(Amount) to Sum(amount).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the `partition by` argument

```
datediff(MINUTE, lag(date) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY to_qw, d_date), date)
```